# Launchrock Widget position

Tags: html, css

I want to change the position of Launchrock and reduce the margin-left.

I have a css file `ignition 1.1.css` but don't know where set the margin of launchrock.

Comment: Can you explain more of your question? perhaps include screenshots, and any code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following blog article.

http://launchrock.com/blog/customize-the-launchrock-widget-to-eamlessly-match-your-site

It looks like you would need to amend the class `lrdiscoverwidget` in the file `ignition 1.1.css`

Something like...

```
.lrdiscoverwidget {
  margin-left: 10px; // add, edit, the desired margin-left.
  //rest of existing rdiscoverwidget css
}
```